# Laravel Eloquent Modal - First Row?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Inside od a Seeder File I tried to get the first record of my User-Model.
However I can't seem to find the correct way.

I want to fetch the first user, and get its id to use it in `user_id` (foreign key).

This is not working:

```
class TerminalsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
    $user = User::findOrFail(1)->first();

    DB::table('terminals')->delete();
    Terminal::create([
        'serial' => 'R-123-548-753',
        'state' => 1,
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);


   }
}
```

It fails because I said "1", but it requires one parameter, my first row in user doesn't have an id of 1, but I don't want to hardcode this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is to use the **firstOrFail**

```
$user = User::firstOrFail(); //it will return the first record from the top
Terminal::create([
  'serial' => 'R-123-548-753',
  'state' => 1,
  'user_id' => $user->id'
])
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first user found or not

```
$user = User::first(); //  returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it returns null
if($user)
    Terminal::create([
      'serial' => 'R-123-548-753',
      'state' => 1,
      'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);
}
```

If user found then it will create new record in terminal.